# Make whole table-row a link

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a table that has a different link for each row. The-clicking-area must fill the whole table-row.
And please: No Javascript! And if possible no additional Div-elements.

This is what I got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/WLYW3/

this works pretty good, but there are some problems:
After adding `height: 128px;` to the a-elements (which seemed necessary), the text in each row wasn't vertically centered anymore. Adding `vertical-align: middle;` didn't help.
And I can't get the table to have rounded corners. (`border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;`).

Comment: By the way, in your bottom row you have three slashes outside of the href value. href="url"/ instead of href="url/"

Comment: words 'And please: No Javascript!' in today apps sounds like 'please no flour' in bread. I do this through javascript and i'ts normal

Answer (score 2):

To fix it, simply add this :

```
#itemTable tbody tr td a
{
    line-height: 128px;
}
```

Comment: This makes the rows way bigger than they should be and still doesn't fill the whole rows.

Comment: When I tested, Alexandre's solution did the trick and it didn't make the table rows higher.

Comment: Wow I must have done somehting wrong the last time I checked it. I think I accidently removed the normal height. This works great

Comment: @Forivin I've not seen the rounded corner part, but nkmol's solution works so I won't copy him :)

Answer (score 2):

### Vertical alignment

Because you use the `<table>` elements, **you can just make the anchor 100% height**. 
Combined with `vertical-align: middle;`, which is used on the `<tbody>` by default, it will calculate the middle based on the total height (100%):

```
#itemTable tbody tr td a { 
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  /*height: 128px;*/
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
```

### Table radius

A table without a border actually does not support the border-radius property and there is no clean solution, you can only force it.

However, even though you did not want an extra element, a wrapper would be the most clean solution:

```
#tableWrapper
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLYW3/2/)

Comment: the rounded corners work fine now. But the link-area does not fill the whole row anymore..

Comment: @Forivin I see. But if you want it your way you're breaking the HTML table design. If you want to do this, i suppose this is not for tabular data. I suggest you to re-create the table with css.